# Image processing Iphone

Tags: iphone

I like to develop a hair styling application for which allows the user to take a picture and try different predefined hair styles.I need to correctly place the predefined hair in correct position of image.I really don't know from where i need to start.If any one have any ideas please share it. Thanks in advance .....

Comment: Why is your question in a code block?

Comment: Thanks phooze that was a mistake....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start looking into OpenCV (image processing library) to detect the eyes position and face bounds. You can then compute the location where the hair has to be placed over.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/eyes.aspx - A sample project which exactly answers you